# Using double wills?

Tags: tense, modal-verbs

Can you use two wills when talking about the future?

When talking about the future, people usually use one present tense and one future tense, right? For example,

> "I **will** take care of that for you so that your life **can be** easier"

But I'm wondering if I can use two wills and say the following for these kinds of sentences:

> "I **will** take care of that for you so that your life **will be** easier"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fine. The present > future pattern is 'usual' only in conditional constructions:

> If he **does** this, I **will do** that.

In these the 'tense' forms aren't really time references. I *will do* isn't any more futurive than the *does* - it signifies subsequence or consequence relative to the *if* clause rather than an actual temporal relationship to the time of utterance.

In other contexts, the restrictions on using future constructions in consecutive clauses are logical and factual, not grammatical. All of these are OK:

> He will do this and I will do that.
>   He will do this to insure that I will do that.
>   He will do this, consequently I will do that.

As for the question TecBrat raises:
In your first sentence, the *can* is only 'present' tense in **form**; its reference is just as futurive as the *will* in your second sentence.  The fact is, English doesn't have a 'present' form, despite the name. The two tenses in English verb forms are not *past* and *present* but *past* and ***non-past***, and the 'present' form can be used with either present or future reference.

> I'm in your neighbourhood tomorrow evening—want to get together for a drink?

When you get right down to it, this is the *only* way to express future reference with *can*. Full modal verbs like *can* cannot be used with auxiliaries like *will* and *be* and *have*, because they are defective—they do not have the non-finite forms (infinitive and participles) which the auxiliaries require.

Comment: I'll certainly agree with that!

Comment: Hmm, I was going to ask a new question on something similar. Can I ask you this before I do? Then is present perfect as futuristic as present tense and future tense? "Let me know if I need to make corrections after you **have received** it and **have reviewed** it"--are the present perfect verbs used in this sentence basically as futuristic as "Let me know if I need to make corrections after you **receive** and **review** it"? I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: @jess The perfect's just fine there - though I'd flip the clauses: *After you have ... let me know ... * Imperative, after all, is inherently futurive.

Comment: @ StoneyB So the difference between the two sentences in my comments is stylistic, right? I can either choose to use present tense or present perfect and still convey the same meaning? Wow, there are so many different ways to say the same thing in English!

Comment: @ StoneyB Even with "will", the next two sentences are interchangeable, right? Like, these two sentences both refer to a future event? "I will do it as soon as I **get** home" = "I will do it as soon as I **have arrived** at home"

Comment: @Jess Exactly. *I have Xed* is a statement about the 'present', but *as soon as I have Xed* is a statement about a hypothetical 'present' which lies (if anywhere) in the 'future' with respect to 'now'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the second sentence makes sense.

Perhaps another answerer can explain better than I can, how "your life can be easier" actually makes sense as a future event, regardless of the apparent tense of the "be" verb, "can".